# MySql ORDER BY slow with join, fast with 2 queries

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, query-optimization

Why is the following query slow but fast when I provide the values inline?

```
select u.* from user u
join user_group g on u.group_id = g.id
where g.account_id = 1
order by u.id limit 10;
-- takes ~30ms
```

```
select id from user_group where account_id = 1;
-- which is (99,198,297,396,495,594,693,792,891,990)

select * from user
where group_id in (99,198,297,396,495,594,693,792,891,990)
order by id limit 10;
-- takes ~1ms
```

Sub query is also slow. The plan is the same as the join.

```
select u.* from user u
where u.group_id in (select id from user_group where account_id = 1)
order by u.id limit 10;
-- ~30ms
```

All queries produce the same result.

```
98  0   99
197 0   198
296 0   297
395 0   396
494 0   495
593 0   594
692 0   693
791 0   792
890 0   891
989 0   990
```

### Schema

I've got the following simple table structure, with 100 accounts 1k user_groups and 10 million users.

```
create table account(
  id int primary key auto_increment
);

create table user_group(
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  account_id int not null,
  foreign key (account_id) references account(id)
);

create table user(
  id int primary key auto_increment,  
  deleted tinyint default 0,
  group_id int not null,
  foreign key (group_id) references user_group(id)
);

-- I've been trying with this index, but it doesnt seem to help.
create index user_1 on user(group_id, id, deleted);
```

### Plans

[image: fast explain]

The plan with the join using indexes and doing temporary filesort.
[image: slow explain]

I don't understand why MySql seems to think it needs actually do the complete join to filter the data down. We clearly don't read anything from `user_group`.

For comparison I've tried the same thing in PostgreSQL and both queries run fast.

Why is it slow and is there a way to write the query (a single query!) that does it quickly? Sub select doesnt work.

This dbfiddle shows the problem.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ed68310d8ca72e9daef389dc0469a6f

Using MySql 8.0.23

Thanks

### Edit

Here are the complete Session Status Handler debug details. It looks like the slow query is reading every value unlike the fast one.

```
-- FLUSH STATUS;
-- select u.* from user u join user_group g on u.group_id = g.id where g.account_id = 1 order by u.id limit 10;
-- SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';

Handler_commit  1
Handler_delete  0
Handler_discover    0
Handler_external_lock   4
Handler_mrr_init    0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  0
Handler_read_key    11
Handler_read_last   0
Handler_read_next   100110
Handler_read_prev   0
Handler_read_rnd    0
Handler_read_rnd_next   0
Handler_rollback    0
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  0
Handler_write   0
```

```
-- FLUSH STATUS;
-- set @uGroups := (select group_concat(id) from user_group where account_id = 1 group by account_id);
-- select * from user where group_id in (select @uGroups) order by id limit 10;
-- SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';

Handler_commit  2
Handler_delete  0
Handler_discover    0
Handler_external_lock   4
Handler_mrr_init    0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  0
Handler_read_key    2
Handler_read_last   0
Handler_read_next   19
Handler_read_prev   0
Handler_read_rnd    0
Handler_read_rnd_next   0
Handler_rollback    0
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  0
Handler_write   0
```

Comment: Please run the timings again; this could be a caching issue.  (30ms is barely worth noting).  Also get the Handler counts:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Comment: The "Rows" in the EXPLAIN are bogus when a LIMIT is involved.  The JOIN _did_ use the index -- notice user_1, test.g.id, and Using index.  But ignore the 9982.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames.

The 30ms is 30x worse in this test data set. In production I have seen queries go from minutes to a few milliseconds.

The handler status shows `read_next = 100110` which is the entire filtered query result. So it seems its not able to use the index to order and limit, like it can in the other queries.

Comment: How many rows were returned by each approach?  The second approach seems to check for only one option, namely the single item "11,22,33,44".  It may return only the row with id=11.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames. Each query produces the same 10 ordered results. There was a bug in the variable query, which was accidentally doing a string comparison. I've removed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using straight_join gets the performance I expected.

```
select straight_join u.* from user u
join user_group g on u.group_id = g.id
where g.account_id = 1
order by u.id limit 10;
```

Thanks Akina https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/289710/227119